# Run fitSmoothHazard function using GPU in R

Tags: r, gpu

I'm trying to run a fitSmoothHazard model with around 100k observation dataset. It is using all my 64Gb of ram, and still not running. It returns an error "cannot allocate vector of size 25.2 Gb". I was thinking if there is a way of running this function on my GPU somehow.

```
model1 <- fitSmoothHazard(transplant_crr ~ time_tx + age_bin + sex + region, 
                          date = tx, 
                          ratio = 100,
                          time = "time_tx")
```